# Use the standard icons/glyphs provided by iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add the standard iOS 7 telephone icon used in the phone app to one of my buttons. How do I do this in Xcode? Can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only the following system tab bar items can be used by third party developers and the phone tab isn't one of them.  If you really are just looking for the icon, its not available either.  The closest thing you can do is create your own.

```
typedef enum {
   UITabBarSystemItemMore,
   UITabBarSystemItemFavorites,
   UITabBarSystemItemFeatured,
   UITabBarSystemItemTopRated,
   UITabBarSystemItemRecents,
   UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
   UITabBarSystemItemHistory,
   UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks,
   UITabBarSystemItemSearch,
   UITabBarSystemItemDownloads,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostRecent,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostViewed,
} UITabBarSystemItem;
```